# How can I run the console code of Kotlin in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm learning Coroutines of Kotlin, many sample codes such as Code A run under console.

At present I have to test it online at https://play.kotlinlang.org/, it's too slow.

How can I run theses codes in  Android Studio?

**Code A**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main()=runBlocking{
     val job = launch {
       val child = launch {
         try {
            delay(Long.MAX_VALUE)
         } finally {
            println("1. Child is cancelled")
         }
     }

      yield()
      println("2. Cancelling child")

      child.cancel()
      child.join()

      yield()
      println("3. Parent is not cancelled")
    }
    job.join()
}
```

**Added Content**

Thanks!

But I can't get result when I run the code, I only get the information "fun main(): Unit"!

**Image A**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried [Kotlin REPL](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/quick-run.html) In Android Studio: Tools->Kotlin->Kotlin REPL or File->Scratch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally use a scratch file `File > New > Scratch File` (mac shortcut Cmd ⌘ Shift N) type kotlin.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: You have to remove the main method. When you create a Java scratch file, IntelliJ IDEA automatically adds a class declaration and a main() method. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scratches.html